# RStudio - How to create a WordCloud with spanish characters like: à,è,ì,ò,ù,ñ

Tags: r, character-encoding

I'm importing a txt file with words in spanish, because I want to create wordCloud...

The problem is that I get this words without accent marks inside my wordcloud...

[image: WordCloud Image]
There are words like: "México" that are displayed as "mc3a9xico" ???

```
text <- readLines(file.choose())
# Load the data as a corpus
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
# Convert the text to lower case
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
# Remove numbers
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
# Remove english common stopwords
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
# Remove your own stop word
# specify your stopwords as a character vector
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("blabla1", "blabla2")) 
# Remove punctuations
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
# Eliminate extra white spaces
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
# Text stemming
# docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 10)
set.seed(1234)
#Generate WordCloud
wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
      max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

Comment: Also known as ["Unicode characters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (since [we've hopefully moved passed the time of codepages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)).

Comment: Could you put together a reproducible example?  Instead of reading your text from a file that we don't have, why not put a small sample of the `d` dataframe right into the code?  And tell us what packages you are using.

Comment: Most of that _looks_ like code from `tm`. Where's `wordcloud` from. You were asked to ensure all 3rd party `library()` calls were in the question when you opened up a question/reviewed the R SO FAQ.

Comment: If this is the `wordcloud::wordcloud()` function I cannot reproduce your error. `wordcloud(c("México", "corrupción"), c(10, 5))` shows the proper glyphs.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I used your line of code <code>wordcloud(c("México", "corrupción"), c(10, 5))</code> And "México" is showing as "M..xico" and "Corrupción" is showing as "Corrupci..n" Am I missing something?

Comment: Likely something to do with your system locale. Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()` into the question?

Comment: @hrbrmstr System locale is showing "C" I think that's the problem, but I don't know how to change it :/ 

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't set my System Locale. So after trying several times to change to spanish, I was getting this error: "OS reports request to set locale to "sp_MX.UTF-8" cannot be honored" So I ended up using this:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
```

And after that everything was working.

Thanks to @hrbrmstr He pointed me to the actual problem :)